# updating data in many-to-many relationship in entity framework in code first existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am working on app and struggling to really understand how to update data in tables where we have intermediate join table (i.e. table to break many-to-many relationship). for example, from following diagram. if I say I want to add record for new student with list of three courses i.e. math, English and computing. how I do that where I have

```
public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
```

[image]

another questions; another scenario if I have courses already and of-course I don't want duplication of math, English and computing course title, how I add new instance of student record there??

### Student

```
 public partial class Student
 {
    public Student()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

### Course

```
 public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

### Intermediate model

```
public partial class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentCourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

My third question is, do I have to use Virtual key word in above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you do not have an additional field in `StudentCourse` (such semester of the registration), then you do not need to have `StudentCourse` class.

If you want to keep this mode, you can do this:

```
StudentCourse registration = new  StudentCourse();
registration.StudentID = 4;
registration.CourseID = 6;
context.StudentCourses.Add(registration);
context.SaveChanges();
```

These resources may give you further explanation:

https://practiceaspnet.wordpress.com/2015/10/22/code-first-many-to-many-mm-relationships-using-conventions-and-data-annotations/

https://practiceaspnet.wordpress.com/2015/10/30/managing-data-in-many-to-many-relationships-with-entity-framework-code-first/

If you want to check if there is no duplicate, you can simple do these:

```
 if(context.Courses.Where(c => c.Title == 'Math').FirstOrDefault() == null)
 {
     //add the course
 }else {
     //already existing
 }
```

Comment: this is good! I have another question in reference to links you provided above... can I achieve this without using fluent api???

Comment: @toxic why not fluent api? it is not very complicated for this task, and very useful?

Comment: @toxic and yes, data annotations should be enough for this task, and you really do not need `StudentCourse`, also do not forget to mark it as correct answer if it helped :)